# How to write a solr query for retrieving all records with numeric field value less then specified?

Tags: java, syntax, solr, lucene, solrj

Let's assume we have a set of mp3-players with names and prices.

How to write a correct solr query for finding all goods with a certain name and with price less then 100$?

`q = "(name:(ipod) AND price ???? 100.0)"`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't think the query parser supports `<` operator. You have to define a [RangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/RangeQuery.html) explicitly. You can then attach a name query to that using a [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html).

Update: Apparently, I was wrong. In fact, Solr's query parser is smarter than Lucene's. Here is your answer: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/the-standard-query-parser.html#differences-between-lucene-s-classic-query-parser-and-solr-s-standard-query-parser

> field:[* TO 100] finds all field values less than or equal to 100

Answer (score 16):

also note that performancewise you should use a filter query for this:

```
&q=name:ipod&fq=price:[* TO 100]
```

Answer (score 10):

From my knowledge, I do not believe that Solr/Lucene supports greater/less than. It can be done programmatically for things like integers and dates (and in your case, money values, since there are only two decimal places to worry about).

For example, natively, Lucene and Solr query parsers support less than or equal to (<=):

```
?q=name:ipod AND price:[* to 99.99]
```

This would give you the less than 100 dollars that you're looking for, provided the data doesn't involve fractions of a cent.

For things like dates and integers, or other things that have notably finite differences, you can decrement (or in the case of greater than, increment) the value you're going for.

EDIT: Check the documentation for version 6.5 of Solr. It DOES contain exclusive range support.

Essentially, use curly braces to denote less than.

```
?q=name:ipod AND price:{* TO 100}
```